# Is it possible to make an array of char arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, char

Using the Eclipse IDE with jdk-13.0.2 and JavaSE-13, Windows 10 Business on a Dell laptop.

I'm trying to make an array of char arrays for a class project. We can't use Strings, which is why I am trying to make this work.

```
private final int stackSize = 100;
private int top;
private char[] items;
private char[] inside;

public CharArrayStack() {
items = new char[stackSize];
char[] items = {char[] inside, };
top = -1;
```

Above is what I have, but I'm getting a, "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" error.

Comment: Yes, you can have an array of arrays. For an array of character arrays, you'd declare it as `char[][]`.

Comment: These are called 2dimensional arrays. Similarly you can have 3d, 4d etc. 1d -> `char[]` , 2d->  `char[][]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [two-dimensional](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/multidimensional-array) array will work for you.

```
char[][] items = new char[][];
```

You can initialize it in different ways:

```
char[][] items = {
      {'a', 'b', 'c'}, 
      {'a', 'b', 'c'}, 
      {'a'}, 
};
```